# sonarqube: specify a C# solution, but also have non C# issues checked

Tags: c#, sonarqube, fxcop, stylecop

I've (succesfully) used SonarQube to analyse a C# project. As I wanted to have it check for more issues, I used the Visual Studio Bootstrapper plugin (sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=MyVisualStudioCode/MyCSharpSolution.sln).

This works fine, but now it only counts lines for the C# code, and not anymore for the java code and html code which is also in the folder.

I guess this is desired behavior, but is there a possibility to have both? To have the extra issues of FxCop and StyleCop but also the analysis on non-c# code? If yes: how?

Thanks a lot and regard!

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Bootstrapper (and its upcoming MSBuild Runner replacement) only import files that added to your MSBuild `.*proj` project files.

For example, HTML files should be added explicitly to the project as content.
It is **not** sufficient to simply drop them under the folder or a sub-folder of your project.

Once that is done, the SonarQube Java and Web plugins for instance will be able to analyze those files, and metrics will be computed correctly.